# Remover Item Null de um ComboBox c#

Tags: c#, combobox, null

Olá,
Estou precisando desenvolver um filtro avançado de pesquisa. Criei alguns comboBoxs para as palavras chaves, mas sempre que preciso buscar o conteúdo de uma coluna que eventualmente tem menos conteúdo que outra determinada coluna, o comboBox é preenchido com as Cells em Null.

Sistema em Run.
[image: Sistema em Execução.]

Breve exemplo do DB.
[image: Um breve exemplo do banco de dados.]

o 1º Combo estou carregando no Form_Load:

```
        OleDbConnection Con = new OleDbConnection();
        Con.ConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.dbConTeste;

        try
        {
            Con.Open();
            OleDbCommand Cmm = new OleDbCommand();
            Cmm.CommandText = "SELECT marca FROM tbmodelo";
            Cmm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            Cmm.Connection = Con;
            OleDbDataReader DR;
            DR = Cmm.ExecuteReader();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(DR);

            DataView dv = new DataView(dt, "", "marca", DataViewRowState.OriginalRows);
            comboBox1.DataSource = dv;
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "marca";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "";

        }
        catch 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error");
        }
        Con.Close();
```

o 2º Combo carrego no evento ComboBox1_Leave:

```
        OleDbConnection Con1 = new OleDbConnection();
        Con1.ConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.dbConTeste;

        try
        {
            Con1.Open();
            OleDbCommand Cmm = new OleDbCommand();
            Cmm.CommandText = "SELECT " + comboBox1.Text + " FROM tbmodelo";
            Cmm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            Cmm.Connection = Con1;
            OleDbDataReader DR;
            DR = Cmm.ExecuteReader();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(DR);


            DataView dv = new DataView(dt, "", comboBox1.Text, DataViewRowState.OriginalRows);
            comboBox2.DataSource = dv;
            comboBox2.DisplayMember = comboBox1.Text;
            comboBox2.ValueMember = "";
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error");
        }
        Con1.Close();
```

Alguém indica uma forma mais simples de carregar os Combos sem os campos em branco? ou apenas excluir os campos em Null. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
OleDbConnection Con = new OleDbConnection();
    Con.ConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.dbConTeste;

    try
    {
        Con.Open();
        OleDbCommand Cmm = new OleDbCommand();
        Cmm.CommandText = "SELECT marca FROM tbmodelo where MARCA <> ''";
        Cmm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        Cmm.Connection = Con;
        OleDbDataReader DR;
        DR = Cmm.ExecuteReader();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(DR);

        DataView dv = new DataView(dt, "", "marca", DataViewRowState.OriginalRows);
        comboBox1.DataSource = dv;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "marca";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "";

    }
    catch 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("error");
    }
    Con.Close()

OleDbConnection Con1 = new OleDbConnection();
    Con1.ConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.dbConTeste;

    try
    {
        Con1.Open();
        OleDbCommand Cmm = new OleDbCommand();
        Cmm.CommandText = "SELECT " + comboBox1.Text + " FROM tbmodelo where " + comboBox1.Text + " <> '';
        Cmm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        Cmm.Connection = Con1;
        OleDbDataReader DR;
        DR = Cmm.ExecuteReader();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(DR);


        DataView dv = new DataView(dt, "", comboBox1.Text, DataViewRowState.OriginalRows);
        comboBox2.DataSource = dv;
        comboBox2.DisplayMember = comboBox1.Text;
        comboBox2.ValueMember = "";
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("error");
    }
    Con1.Close();
```

Comment: Só pra constar que se o valor do campo for `NULL` (e não vazio), não vai funcionar.